# convert System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography to System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, xamarin, spatial

In a portable project I have `Event` model.

```
    //Event.cs 
    using System.Data.Spatial;
    public class Event
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public EventType EventType { get; set; }
            [JsonConverter(typeof(DbGeographyConverter))]
            public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
        }
```

I am using this model in backend project and also in Android project. 
In backend project I have installed Entity Framework 6. There is no `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography` class but  `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` class exists.

When I try to create new Event class in my Backend project, compilator throws error:

> Cannot convert source type `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` to `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography`.

What options do I have?

I can change `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography` to `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` in my `Event` class but then I could not use `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` in my Android project. (cannot install Entity Framework).

Answer (score 0):

Both classes are almost identical with Entity Framework one having an extra `Provider` property.

You can use Automapper to map from EF class to .NET class. Or you can simply carbon copy a new property in your `Event` class:

```
using System.Data.Spatial;
public class Event
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public EventType EventType { get; set; }            
        public  System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Location { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(DbGeographyConverter))]
        public System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography ConvertedLocation 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return new System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography()
                {
                    Area = this.Location.Area,
                    //all other properties except Provider
                    //...
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to switch between the namespaces i use extensions:

```
public static class DatabaseExtensions
{
    public static DbGeography ToFrameworkGeography(this System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography geography)
    {
        return DbGeography.FromText(geography.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText, geography.CoordinateSystemId);
    }

    public static DbGeometry ToFrameworkGeometry(this System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry geometry)
    {
        return DbGeometry.FromText(geometry.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText, geometry.CoordinateSystemId);
    }

    public static System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography ToSystemGeography(this DbGeography geography)
    {
        return System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(geography.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText, geography.CoordinateSystemId);
    }

    public static System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry ToSystemGeometry(this DbGeometry geometry)
    {
        return System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromText(geometry.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText, geometry.CoordinateSystemId);
    }
}
```